# JNI is crashing the java in windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, java-native-interface

I am porting a code from linux to windows and since there is no support for Linux shared memory segments in Java. Hence, we are using  the Java Native Interface (JNI) to access shared memory.It is working fine on linux platform .

Code for shmget:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_emulatorinterface_communication_shm_SharedMem_shmget
(JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj, jint COUNT,jint MaxNumJavaThreads,jint EmuThreadsPerJavaThread,
        jlong coremap, jint pid) {

    uint64_t mask = coremap;

    int size;//=sizeof(packet)*(COUNT+5)*MaxNumJavaThreads*EmuThreadsPerJavaThread;

    char str[50];
    int ptr;

#ifdef _WIN32
    HANDLE hMapFile;
#endif
    printf("hello");
    size=sizeof(packet)*(COUNT+5)*MaxNumJavaThreads*EmuThreadsPerJavaThread;
    /*if (sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(mask), (cpu_set_t *)&mask) <0) {
        perror("sched_setaffinity");
    }*/


    //set the global variables
    gCOUNT = COUNT;
    gMaxNumJavaThreads = MaxNumJavaThreads;
    gEmuThreadsPerJavaThread = EmuThreadsPerJavaThread;

    //size1 is the number of packets needed in the segment.

#ifdef _WIN32

    _itoa(pid,str,10);


    hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
        NULL, PAGE_READWRITE,
        0,32, str);

    if (hMapFile == NULL)
    {

         exit(1);
    }
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);

    hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
        NULL, PAGE_READWRITE,
        0,size, str);

    if (hMapFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to create a shared mem file.");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (hMapFile < 0)
    {
        return (-1);
    }

    /*
    if((hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
        NULL, PAGE_READWRITE,
        0,size, str))<0)
    {
        printf("error window %d\n",size);
        return (-1);
    }
    */
    ptr=*((int*)(hMapFile));

    return ptr;          ///////////////error in return type 
    #else
```

If i am trying to use any other function in JNI ,my java crashes.

error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007feedf911be, pid=4696, tid=4216
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_77-b03) (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.77-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [JNIShm.dll+0x11be]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\workspace\tejasMinor\hs_err_pid4696.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Can anyone point out where is the problem ?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't dereference an `HANDLE` to a File Mapping Object. Just make you function return the handle, as in:

```
return (int)hMapFile;
```

On 64 bits Windows (with a 64 bits JRE/JNI) the `HANDLE` type is 64 bits wide, but only the lower 32 bits are significant, so that's OK.

Side notes:

1. Don't use `hMapFile < 0`. If the API fails, the return value is `NULL`.
2. Are you sure you need to try at first with a 32 bytes file, then close it? Why?
3. You may want to call `GetLastError` and test the result against `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` (if you want to be able to detect that condition)

Comment: Thanks for replying back.I did the required changes.Now i am getting ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS for first few time in a loop and later it is giving correct value.Why is it happening ?How can i correct it?

Comment: @kunal That's another question. Did my answer help you with the crash? When `CreateFileMapping` says that the Memory Mapped Named Object already exists, that means just that... If you want to open an already existing object, use `OpenFileMapping`. Plus: why do you talk about a loop?!?

Comment: Yes ,it helped.Thanks.Ok i will try with OpenFileMapping .It is requirement of my program to run it in a loop and i had added getError logic later to find out the error.But I didn't understand why is it saying file exist fir for few iteration  and then  successfully created the object.Why is it so?

Comment: @Kunal thanks for accepting the answer. When `CreateFileMapping` says that the file already exists, that's not really an error. The returned handle IS valid. That's just an indication that the shared memory has been already created (with that name) and/or has not been "closed", yet. The memory will exist until the last `HANDLE`to it is not "closed".